# How to display none if div tag doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, variable-length

If the "slick-initialized" div tag doesn't exist within a parent, then I want the parent ID (product recommender-recipe) to display none. Right now this is what I have set up:

HTML is set up like this:

```
<div id="product-recommender-recipe">
<div class="slick-initialized">
</div>
</div>
```

My JS so far. If length is 0, then have the parent ID display none. :

```
var productTemplate = document.getElementsByClassName("#product-recommender-recipe > .slick-initialized")
                    if (productTemplate.length === 0){
                        document.getElementById("product-recommender-recipe").style.display = "none";
                    }
```

Do I have this set up properly?

Comment: You need `querySelector` to make CSS-like selections in Javascript

Comment: @Kokodoko - Agree, but strangely the code works even with the id in the selector. Perhaps getElementsByClassName ignores it and just looks at the class?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Any specific reason why this might have gotten a down arrow? So I know for the future.

Comment: @Yogi probably because `productTemplate.length` is always 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. You have two mistakes in your implementation.
The first one is that you used `getElementByClassName` when in fact you are using an ID as your selector. Thus you should have used `querySelector`.

The second one is that you overused your selector. You have selected your parent div and placed it in a var so that you can reference it again.

Here is my implementation:

```js
var productTemplate = document.querySelector("#product-recommender-recipe")
if (!productTemplate.querySelector('.slick-initialized')) {
        productTemplate.style.display = none;
}
```

```css
#product-recommender-recipe {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="product-recommender-recipe">
<div class="slick-initialized"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. looks like i was missing the querySelector and a few other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide `#product-recommender-recipe` and check if `.slick-initialized exists` than show using just CSS.

it is working perfectly.

```css
#product-recommender-recipe {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

#product-recommender-recipe:has(.slick-initialized) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- hidden if slick-initialized not exist -->
<div id="product-recommender-recipe">
<!-- <div class="slick-initialized"></div> -->
</div>
<br/>
<!-- visible if slick-initialized exist -->
<div id="product-recommender-recipe">
  <div class="slick-initialized"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SchneiderG did you manage to fix it? here is my simple answer for your question. if you would like please voteup for appreciation.thanks

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` expects a single class name – not a selector. If you want to use a selector, use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`. `querySelector` returns `null` if the element doesn't exists in the DOM.

```
const element = document.querySelector(".slick-initialized");

if(element === null) {
    document.querySelector("#product-recommender-recipe").style.display = "none";
}
```